# change key to lower case for dict or OrderedDict

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Following works for a dictionary, but not OrderedDict. For od it seems to form an infinite loop. Can you tell me why?
If the function input is dict it has to return dict, if input is OrderedDict it has to return od.

```
def key_lower(d):
    """returns d for d or od for od with keys changed to lower case
    """
    for k in d.iterkeys():
        v = d.pop(k)
        if (type(k) == str) and (not k.islower()):
            k = k.lower()
        d[k] = v

    return d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It forms an infinite loop because of the way ordered dictionaries add new members (to the end)

Since you are using `iterkeys`, it is using a generator.  When you assign `d[k] = v` you are adding the new key/value to the end of the dictionary.  Because you are using a generator, that will continue to generate keys as you continue adding them.

You could fix this in a few ways.  One would be to create a new ordered dict from the previous.

```
def key_lower(d):
     newDict = OrderedDict()
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if (isinstance(k, (str, basestring))):
            k = k.lower()
        newDict[k] = v
    return newDict
```

The other way would be to not use a generator and use `keys` instead of `iterkeys`

Comment: What I thought was once I created the generator it was set. Thank you for clarifying that.
But I do not want to create a new dict, I want to keep the same type dict/orderedDict without testing their types, and therefore keep the same dict.
In that case using d.keys() instead of d.iterkeys() should work.

Comment: But why was it working for dict? the generator should still continue to generate keys, when they are added, and create an infinite loop.

Comment: Switching between upper and lower case keeps the key in the same position provided the size of the dict does not change.  So simply swapping 'ONE' with 'one' as a key will replace the key at the same index. OrderedDict will always append the key/value.

Answer (score 0):

As sberry mentioned, the infinite loop is essentially as you are modifying and reading the dict at the same time.

Probably the simplest solution is to use `OrderedDict.keys()` instead of `OrderedDict.iterkeys()`:

```
for k in d.keys():
    v = d.pop(k)
    if (type(k) == str) and (not k.islower()):
        k = k.lower()
    d[k] = v
```

as the keys are captured directly at the start, they won't get updated as items are changed in the dict.

Comment: using d.keys() works. Thank you.
I wanted to use d.iterkeys() to save some time.